# A problem with auto-pst-pdf and latest update of graphics-def

Tags: bugs

Since last update of `graphics-def` (2017-06-12) I have error messages when using `auto-pst-pdf` and `pstricks`. These error messages involve the `\stockwidth` and `stockheight` lengths, which are defined by the `memoir` class, if I'm not mistaken, which I do not use. Typing `s` in the console nevertheless results in a correct pdf file, with 6 errors, so I wonder whether there's a bug in last update.

Here is a very simple code which produces the errors:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-plot, auto-pst-pdf}%

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
\psaxes[ticks=none, labels=none, arrows=->](0,0)(-3,-3)(3,3)[$x$,-135] [$y$,180]
\uput[dl](0,0){$ O $}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

and the relevant part of the .log file:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \stockwidth 
l.5 \begin{document}

? s
OK, entering \scrollmode...
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \stockwidth 
l.5 \begin{document}

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...tockwidth \paperheight \stockheight 
                                                  \fi \ifdim \paperwidth >\z...
l.5 \begin{document}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \endgroup 
l.5 \begin{document}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \endgroup 
l.5 \begin{document}

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

<pbautopstpdf-pics.pdf, id=2, page=1, pagebox=cropbox, 171.64125pt x 174.6525pt
>
File: pbautopstpdf-pics.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use pbautopstpdf-pics.pdf, page 1>
Package pdftex.def Info: pbautopstpdf-pics.pdf , page1 used on input line 8. on
 input line 8.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 171.64081pt x 174.65207pt on input lin
e 8.
! Undefined control sequence.
\Gin@setfile ...GPT@page \@empty \else (\GPT@page 
                                                  )\fi }
l.8 \psaxes
           [ticks=none, labels=none, arrows=->](0,0)(-3,-3)(3,3)[$x$,-135] [...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I would be very grateful for any explanation/workaround.

Comment: confirmed here, we'll look into it and adjust...

Comment: We are working through a few minor niggles in the updated drivers: probably this will be sorted in tomorrow's release (we've had several!).

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/graphics-def/issues/10